# Fail to update Email Address in All Subscribers via Import Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, support, subscriber-key

We need to update the email address of users in All Subscribers, so we used the following aproach:

- Populate a DE with the users to update, saving Subscriber Key and new email address.
- Export the DE to the FTP.
- Import the file to All Subscribers.

Our problem is that it seems that it's using the email to locate the Subscriber instead of trying to refresh it. The report of the importation gives the following error:

> 0 NotFound [Subscriber Key of the user we were trying to update]

What can be happening here?

Comment: While importing the file, which update option are you selecting?

Comment: @SelimSevim I'm using Update Only

Comment: Have you verified that the DE does not contain people that are not on All Subscribers because that is what that error means. I would run a query on this DE against `_Subscribers` Data View where the subkey in `_Subscribers` is null. This should give you a list of all subscribers that are not currently in your All Subs list but are in your DE.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, yes, we've checked that. In fact, the list we were trying to update was a query from _Subscribers joining other table. We think the problem was that _Subscribers is shared accross all son BUs and maybe only read-accesable, so it fail when trying to update them. It worked fine when updating them from the father BU. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

We've solved the issue. Since we are working with hierarchical BUs, it seems that trying to update All Subscribers from the sons doesn't work.

We have replicated the same Automation we had in the Father BU and it works fine.